# Javascript incrementing itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a form index.asp

```
<div class="wrapper pop-up" id="pop_up" style="display:none;"></div>
<div class="log_in">
        <a href="/Login.asp" class="LogInBut" id="LogIn">Login</a>
</div>
```

Login.asp

```
<div class="authorize" id="authorizeID" >

    <a href="#" id="authorize-closeBut" class="authorize-close">
        <img src="img/icons/cross.png" />
    </a>

    <div id="response"> </div>
    <div class="authorize-footer">
        <a href="/ForgotPassword.asp"  class="LogInBut" id="passremainderBut">ForgotPassword</a>
        <a href="/Register.asp"  class="LogInBut"  id="registrationBut">Registration</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

ForgotPassword.asp

```
<div class="authorize" id="passremainderID" >
    <a href="#" id="passremainder-closeBut" class="authorize-close">
        <img src="img/icons/cross.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

I have a javascript

```
$(".LogInBut").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
            alert($('#pop_up').length);
            if ($('#pop_up').length) {
                $('#pop_up').html(data).show(function() {
                    $('.authorize-close').click(function(e){      
                        e.preventDefault();
                        if ($('#pop_up').length) {
                            $('#pop_up').html("");
                            $('#pop_up').hide(); 
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
});
```

So if i insert this javascript into Index.asp page and click #LogIn, I got pop-up window with Login.asp and once alert($('#pop_up').length);, if i click on `.authorize-close` windows will close. If i click #LogIn again i got the same but alert($('#pop_up').length); appears twice and so incrementing each time i click #LogIn.

So how to prevent incrementing and show only once this alert?

Comment: You should delegate event instead http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ and not binding it on each ajax success callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everytime you click the button.. you are creating a new event click for #pop_up

```
$('.authorize-close').click(function(e){
```

Its showing twice, because you created the event twice. you need to delete the old event, than create again.. change the line to:

```
$('.authorize-close').unbind('click').bind('click',function(e){
```

Comment: Do not make any effect, alert still incrementing

Comment: It shouldn't increment, there is no logic for that. Sometimes is a plugin in browser or something that put content to html..   Try to change your alert to this code to check the elements:   for(i =0; i< $('#pop_up').length; i++) alert( $('#pop_up')[i] + " with id #"+$('#pop_up')[i].id + ", classes: ."+ $('#pop_up')[i].className.split(' ').join(', .') );

Comment: Working if i place $(".LogInBut").unbind('click');  before last `}); ` in  `$(".LogInBut").on('click', function(e) {`